# Starting another activity when one activity is about to start: Android

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I have an app where I have to show the Splash Screen every time the user comes to the app. That is whether he launches the app afresh or whthere he foregrouds he app, or whether he clicks on the launcher icon.

The issue is that after the splash screen i also want to go back to the last activity that was on visible when he left the app (in case it is not a fresh start)

To solve this I extended Application and implemented the ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.

SO when my app was in the bacground and came back to foregroud, I would launch the Splash  screen from

```
@Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
     //launch splash screen
}
```

Now once the splash screens work is done i kill it and I am back to whatever activity was there when the user last using the app before the app went to the background.

Here it seems to be working fine but i keep getting the following error:

```
09-14 16:44:46.746: E/ActivityThread(5622): Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: {SignInActivity}
09-14 16:44:46.746: E/ActivityThread(5622): java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: {SignInActivity}
09-14 16:44:46.746: E/ActivityThread(5622):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3015)
09-14 16:44:46.746: E/ActivityThread(5622):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3003)
09-14 16:44:46.746: E/ActivityThread(5622):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2981)
09-14 16:44:46.746: E/ActivityThread(5622):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-14 16:44:46.746: E/ActivityThread(5622):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
09-14 16:44:46.746: E/ActivityThread(5622):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-14 16:44:46.746: E/ActivityThread(5622):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-14 16:44:46.746: E/ActivityThread(5622):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
09-14 16:44:46.746: E/ActivityThread(5622):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 16:44:46.746: E/ActivityThread(5622):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-14 16:44:46.746: E/ActivityThread(5622):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
09-14 16:44:46.746: E/ActivityThread(5622):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
09-14 16:44:46.746: E/ActivityThread(5622):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So I have two questions:

1. What do i do so that this error does not come.
2. Is there a better way to handle the flow that i mentioned above: that i have to show the splash screen and then take the sure to the last visible activity?

Thanks,
Sunny

Comment: post your related codes.

Comment: how do you handle SignInActivity ?

Answer (score 0):

Into the Oncreate Method you can start an `ActivityForResult`

```
startActivityForResult(intent, activity);
```

and then follow your activity with:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

Comment: Ok, tell me about news!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to show the last activity even after the app has been completely destroyed/terminated. You will need persistent data to achieve that I think. I used shared preferences below as an example (haven't tested it but I hope you get the idea).

```
//Inside every activity of your app
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    //Store the current activity name inside shared preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("LastActivity", getCurrentActivityName());
    editor.commit();
    //Show splash screen here every time the app is brought to foreground (aka it resumes)
}

private void openActivityFromName(String name){
    Class<?> c = null;
    if(name != null) {
        try {
            c = Class.forName(name);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private String getCurrentActivityName(){
    this.getClass().getSimpleName()
}

/**
* Inside your main activity (the one that opens first normally)
*/
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
    super.onCreate(state);   
    // Restore preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String lastActivity = settings.getString("LastActivity", "");
    //Open the last opened activity everytime the app opens 
    openActivityFromName(lastActivity);
}
```

Bringing your app to the background (not closing it) will not close your current activity. So the behavior of opening the last activity is only needed once the app has been destroyed completely and `onCreate` is called again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just want to show the last activity if there exits one, else i just go to a particular activity after showing the splash screen. but the point is that I have to show the splash screen before showing the previous activity and hence the error comes that i have pasted above.

Comment: one more thing. if i start the splash screen after onResume of the previous activity is called then it woudl be visible to the user first and then the splash screen and then the previous activity again. I want that the user not see the previous activity untill the splash screen is done

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I think you should just put onResume method and eventually onPause() method to control state of your activity.

put onResume() method

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
 super.onResume();
...//
}
```